# JSON.Net Ignore Property during deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a class set up as follows:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string string1 { get; set; }
    public string string2 { get; set; }
    public string string3 { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Json.Net to deserialize the following Json Response:

```json
[
    {
        "number1": 1,
        "number2": 12345678901234567890,
        "number3": 3
    },
    {
        "number1": 9,
        "number2": 12345678901234567890,
        "number3": 8
    }
]
```

Deserialization code:

```
string json = @"[
    {
        ""number1"": 1,
        ""number2"": 12345678901234567890,
        ""number3"": 3
    },
    {
        ""number1"": 9,
        ""number2"": 12345678901234567890,
        ""number3"": 8
    }
]"

List<Foo> foos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Foo>>(json);
```

The value in `number2` exceeds an `Int64`, but I don't really care about retrieving that value. Is there a way to cast the `number2` property to a string, or fully ignore it during deserialization?

I have tried adding the `[JsonConverter(typeof(string))]` attribute to the `string2` property, but recieve the error: `Error creating System.String`. I have also tried setting `typeof(decimal)`.

I have also tried using `[JsonIgnore]` but that doesn't work.

Comment: I solved the issue by using a Regex.Replace() to remove the entry:

string fixedResponse = Regex.Replace(json, "\\\"number2\\\": \\d+, " ,String.Empty);

Comment: Why don't you post a proper answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054986/removing-an-element-from-a-json-response

Answer (score 44):

You can use `MissingMemberHandling` property of the `JsonSerializerSettings` object.

Example usage:

```cs
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(jsonResponse, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

More info [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm).

Comment: he is asking to ignore specific key not handle missing key, you answer is irrelevant to the question

Comment: it's interesting still how many of us were searching for actually this answer - i.e. we had a different question, but the answer we got was right. i am almost feeling surreal

Answer (score 11):

This is a lame workaround but you could make a method to manually load the json. If it's too much data to load without an automatic deserializer just remove the nodes that you don't want. This is a lot slower though.

```
public static List<Foo> FromJson(string input) {
    var json = JToken.Parse(input);
    json["key"].Remove();
    var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Foo>>(json.ToString());

}
```

This is an interesting problem I wonder if anyone has a better solution for it.

Comment: This code errors at JToken.Parse(input), it still can't parse a uInt64 :/

Comment: That sucks it looks like Regex is your best friend right now. Maybe submit an issue with the Json.net people.

Answer (score 10):

Here's the Newtonsoft Json preferred way to ignore a property without having to modify the class as based on http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ReducingSerializedJSONSize.htm

This one is used to ignore lazy reference properties of EF or Linq2Sql

```
public class DynamicContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, 
        MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        Func<Type,bool> includeProperty = t => t.IsValueType || t.Namespace.StartsWith("System") && t.Namespace.StartsWith("System.Data")==false; 
        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        var allProperties = properties.Select (p => new{p.PropertyName,Including=includeProperty(p.PropertyType), p.PropertyType});//.Dump("props");
        var warnProperties=allProperties.Where (a =>a.Including && a.PropertyType.IsValueType==false && a.PropertyType.Name.IsIgnoreCaseMatch("String")==false) ;

        //linq pad debugging helper
        //var propertyTypesSerializing= allProperties.Where (p => p.Including).Select (p => p.PropertyType).Distinct().OrderBy (p => p.Name).Dump();

        if(warnProperties.Any())
        {
            //LinqPad helper
            //Util.Highlight(warnProperties.ToArray()).Dump("warning flag raised, aborting");
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        properties = properties.Where(p =>includeProperty(p.PropertyType)).ToList();
        return properties;
    }
}
```

All the `.Dump()` calls are just linqpad debugging helpers, not needed method calls.

sample usage:

```
var inactives = from am in Aspnet_Memberships
        join mm in Member_members on am.UserId equals mm.Member_guid
        where mm.Is_active==false && mm.Org_id==1
        select new{am,mm};
        //inactives.Take(4).ToArray().Dump();
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            inactives.Skip(1).Select(i => i.mm).First(), 
            new  JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ContractResolver = new DynamicContractResolver(), 
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
                ReferenceLoopHandling= ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            }); 
            //.Dump();
```

Comment: `.IsIgnoreCaseMatch`?, Does that mean `.Equals("String", StringComparison.[xIgnoreCase])` ?

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [@Maslow's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21758478/1037948), you can use [another general purpose "ignorer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851899/is-there-a-way-to-make-javascriptserializer-ignore-properties-of-a-certain-gener/14510098#14510098):

```
var jsonResolver = new IgnorableSerializerContractResolver();
// ignore your specific property
jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(Foo), "string2");
// ignore single datatype
jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject));
var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, ContractResolver = jsonResolver };
```

Comment: That is for ignores during serialization, this question is about deserialization.

Comment: @Alrehamy what? To quote the question > "...or fully ignore it during deserialization"

Comment: Years later based on [@ohad-bitton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51011104/1037948) I think the resolver _doesn't_ work both ways.  Oh well.

Comment: I ran into the same thing, but was able to fix it by overriding the `CreateProperties` method:

`        protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

            foreach (var p in Ignores.SelectMany((type) => type.Value))
            {
                properties.Add(new JsonProperty() { PropertyName = p });
            }
            return properties;
        }`

Answer (score 3):

this code worked like a charm to me:

```
using System.Reflection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
public class PropertyRenameAndIgnoreSerializerContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, HashSet<string>> _ignores;
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, string>> _renames;

    public PropertyRenameAndIgnoreSerializerContractResolver()
    {
        _ignores = new Dictionary<Type, HashSet<string>>();
        _renames = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }

    public void IgnoreProperty(Type type, params string[] jsonPropertyNames)
    {
        if (!_ignores.ContainsKey(type))
            _ignores[type] = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var prop in jsonPropertyNames)
            _ignores[type].Add(prop);
    }

    public void RenameProperty(Type type, string propertyName, string newJsonPropertyName)
    {
        if (!_renames.ContainsKey(type))
            _renames[type] = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        _renames[type][propertyName] = newJsonPropertyName;
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (IsIgnored(property.DeclaringType, property.PropertyName))
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = i => false;
            property.Ignored = true;
        }

        if (IsRenamed(property.DeclaringType, property.PropertyName, out var newJsonPropertyName))
            property.PropertyName = newJsonPropertyName;

        return property;
    }

    private bool IsIgnored(Type type, string jsonPropertyName)
    {
        if (!_ignores.ContainsKey(type))
            return false;

        return _ignores[type].Contains(jsonPropertyName);
    }

    private bool IsRenamed(Type type, string jsonPropertyName, out string newJsonPropertyName)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> renames;

        if (!_renames.TryGetValue(type, out renames) || !renames.TryGetValue(jsonPropertyName, out newJsonPropertyName))
        {
            newJsonPropertyName = null;
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

//ignore number2 in Foo Example

```
public class Foo
{
public string number1 { get; set; }
public string number2 { get; set; }
public string number3 { get; set; }
}
    string Foojson = @"[
    {
        ""number1"": 1,
        ""number2"": 12345678901234567890,
        ""number3"": 3
    },
    {
        ""number1"": 9,
        ""number2"": 12345678901234567890,
        ""number3"": 8
    }
]";
var jsonResolverFoo = new PropertyRenameAndIgnoreSerializerContractResolver();
jsonResolverFoo.IgnoreProperty(typeof(Foo), "number2");
var serializerSettingsFoo = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettingsFoo.ContractResolver = jsonResolverFoo;
var deserializedJsonFoo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Foo>>(Foojson, serializerSettingsFoo);
```

/*
Resource Link: https://blog.rsuter.com/advanced-newtonsoft-json-dynamically-rename-or-ignore-properties-without-changing-the-serialized-class/
*/

Answer (score 1):

Adding to drzaus answer: 
You can use the `DefaultContractResolver` he suggested .. just in its `CreateProperty` use `property.Ignored = true;` instead of `property.ShouldSerialize`, then its good either when you pass the `JsonSerializerSettings` to the `DeserializeObject` function or the `SerializeObject` function.

Comment: Doesn't work for me; I also tried `GetIsSpecified`, and then [tried to look at JsonConvert's source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializer.cs) and I don't actually think it's possible.  Maybe substitute the `property.ValueProvider` with some sort of noop?

Comment: i tested it and it did work.. what happened in your case?

Comment: Nothing happened in my case.  It ignored my ignoring of the property and continued to deserialize.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative;

If ResponseAttribute has in model or string parameters

```
public class ResponseAttribute : Attribute { }

public class ModelItem
{
    [Response]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Code;

```
public class CustomJsonSerializer : JsonSerializerSettings
{
    public CustomJsonSerializer()
    {
        ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver();
    }

    public CustomJsonSerializer(params string[] members)
    {
        ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver(members);
    }

    public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        public string[] Members { get; set; }
        public CustomContractResolver(params string[] _members)
        {
            Members = _members;
        }

        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

            if (Members?.Length > 0)
                property.ShouldSerialize = instance => { return Members.Contains(member.Name); };
            else
                property.ShouldSerialize = instance => { return member.GetCustomAttribute<ResponseAttribute>() != null; };

            return property;
        }
    }
}
```

Use;

```
return new JsonResult(model, new CustomJsonSerializer());
```

or

```
return new JsonResult(model, new CustomJsonSerializer("Id","Test","Test2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar but my class contained List<> and Dictionary<> which were populated and should not be overwritten by whatever the JSON file had.  It was easier for me to load the data into a scratch object and then just pull the items I needed as opposed to any other method I could find at the time.

So for this example, something like this...

```
public class Foo
{
    public string string1 { get; set; }
    public string string2 { get; set; }
    public string string3 { get; set; }
}
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

List<Foo> tmp= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Foo>>(json);

foreach(Foo item in tmp)
{
    foos.string1 = tmp.string1;
    foos.string3 = tmp.string3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0

**Any JSON properties that aren't represented in your class are ignored.**