# Newtonsoft.Json deserializing base64 image fails

Tags: c#, .net, json, image

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize the output from my webservice to an object.
It worked fine until I added a `Bitmap`property to my class (named `User`) to hold an avatar.

The webservice is returning that propert as a Base64 string, which is as expected. 
The problem is when I try to convert back the JSON from the WS to a `List<User>`, a `JsonSerializationException` is thrown in this block of code:

```
// T is IList<User>
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Proceed(
    (readTask) =>
    {
        var json = ((Task<string>)readTask).Result;
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json); //<-- it fails here

         // do stuff! 
     });
```

Output from exception is:

```
Error converting value "System.Drawing.Bitmap" to type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'. Path '[2].Avatar
```

and looking at the inner exception:

```
{"Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Drawing.Bitmap."}
```

It's clear that it fails to parse the Base64 string, but it's not clear why.

Any ideas/workaround?

**EDIT**
I know I can use `Convert.FromBase64String` do get a byte array and load a bitmap from that. Then I'd like to update my question to ask about **how** can I skip or manually parse **only** that field. 
I would like to avoid, having to manually parse all the JSON. 
Is this even possible?

**EDIT 2**
I found out the root problem: JSON is not being correctly serialized in webservice (and I fail to see why). I thought that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529904/different-behaviour-in-response-if-acceptapplication-json-is-specified) was a somewhat different issue, but no. My webservice is simply returning a string `"System.Drawing.Bitmap"` instead of its base64 content. Hence the `JsonSerializationException`.

I have been unable to solve that issue, the only solution I've found is to turn my field into a `byte []`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read that field as string,

convert to byte array using `Convert.FromBase64String` and

get the image using  `Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytearray));`

**EDIT**

You can perform image serialization/deserialization with the help of a custom *converter*

```
public class AClass
{
    public Bitmap image;
    public int i;
}

Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"......");
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new AClass() { image = bmp, i = 666 }, 
                                       new ImageConverter());

var aclass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AClass>(json, new ImageConverter());
```

This is the `ImageConverter`

```
public class ImageConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Bitmap);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var m = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String((string)reader.Value));
        return (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(m);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)value;
        MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(m, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToBase64String(m.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer to my edited question. Is there a way to make `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)` skip a field only? This is inside a generic method, so I'd like to avoid a full manual parse...

Comment: With this code I have to manually serialize my object in the webservice, right?

Comment: @Joel no. This code deserializes base64 encoded string to Bitmap if your field/property's type is `Bitmap`. See the definition of `AClass`

Comment: see my update. Your solution is very promising, but I'm unable to test it as the root problem has changed. If I solve that problem I'll be sure to test your solution.

Comment: @Joel Just use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject,new ImageConverter());`

Comment: Finally managed for it to work! Here's my +1. I'll signal this as the right answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is my solution, I used the annotation

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomBitmapConverter))]
    public Bitmap MyImage { get; set; }


    #region JsonConverterBitmap
    internal class CustomBitmapConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return true;
        }

        //convert from byte to bitmap (deserialize)

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            string image = (string)reader.Value;

            byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            return (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(memoryStream);
        }

        //convert bitmap to byte (serialize)
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)value;

            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            writer.WriteValue((byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bitmap, typeof(byte[])));
        }

        public static System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat GetImageFormat(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            ImageFormat img = bitmap.RawFormat;

            if (img.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg))
                return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            if (img.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp))
                return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp;
            if (img.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png))
                return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png;
            if (img.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Emf))
                return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Emf;
            if (img.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Exif))
                return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Exif;
            if (img.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif))
                return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif;
            if (img.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon))
                return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon;
            if (img.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.MemoryBmp))
                return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.MemoryBmp;
            if (img.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff))
                return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff;
            else
                return System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Wmf;
        }

    }

    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Deserializing from `Base64` to `System.Drawing.Bitmap` is not supported. May be you can try deserializing everything excepts the `Avatar` property

**EDIT FOR EDITED QUESTION**

Here is an interesting discussion on how to do that:
[JSON.Net Ignore Property during deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754463/json-net-ignore-property-during-deserialization)

I think the best that you can do is use `Regex` to remove the property from the json string:

```
var newJsonString = Regex.Replace(jsonString, 
                                  "(\\,)* \"Avatar\": \"[A-Za-z0-9]+\"", 
                                  String.Empty);
```

and then deserialize this `newJsonString` without the Avatar property.

Later you can parse the original json string to get the `base64` and build the `Bitmap`

```
var avatarBase64 = Regex.Match(
                        Regex.Match(json, "(\\,)* \"Avatar\": \"[A-Za-z0-9]+\"")
                             .ToString(), 
                        "[A-Za-z0-9]+", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
                        .ToString();

...

byte[] fromBase64 = Convert.FromBase64String(avatarBase64);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fromBase64))
{
    Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
    result.Avatar = img;
}
```

You could improve the regular expressions or the method, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: "you can try deserializing everything excepts the Avatar property..." 
Is there a way to to this without having to manually parse all elements?

Comment: a) Base64 encoding requires 64 chars but I see only 62 in this regex `A-Za-z0-9` b) Trying to parse json with regex is not nice. c) "*I think that the Deserializing from Base64 to System.Drawing.Bitmap is not supported.*" is not correct. d) you can declare the `avatar` field as string and construct the image in c# without regex.