# Different behaviour in response if Accept:application/json is specified

Tags: c#, .net, json

The Http method used is GET and I'm calling the same webservice method (with same parameters).

But if I add to request an Accept header with application/json, the output differs. 
The cause is a Bitmap field in my object named User, which holds an avatar image.

If i leave out the Accept application/json header, this is the simplified output (XML):

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<ArrayOfUser xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XTraN4ForcesFSDomain.Domain">
<User>
    <Id>02ddf1e4-ad76-4778-8887-a186014939f8</Id>
    <Avatar xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Drawing" i:nil="true" />
    <IsActive>false</IsActive>
    <LastAccess>0001-01-01T00:00:00</LastAccess>
    <Username>quisquam</Username>
    <!-- Other properties -->
</User>
<User>
    <Id>17db833c-5008-44f0-a713-a186014c22a5</Id>
    <Avatar xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Drawing">
        <Data xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:base64Binary" xmlns="">iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAAAABGdBTUEAAK/INwWK6[...]BIJS/Wd6Pgu/mOoS/HADwfwFUI4VkJHOgAgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==</Data>
    </Avatar>
    <IsActive>false</IsActive>
    <LastAccess>0001-01-01T00:00:00</LastAccess>
    <Username>labore</Username>
</User>
</ArrayOfUser>
```

Well, this is just fine! The image (Base64) is there. If I change my request to get JSON, it returns no image, just the name of the class that it represents:

```
<!-- language: lang-json -->
[
    {
        "Username": "quisquam",
         "LastAccess": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "IsActive": false,
        "Avatar": null,
        "Id": "02ddf1e4-ad76-4778-8887-a186014939f8"
   },
   {
       "Username": "reiciendis",
       "LastAccess": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
       "IsActive": false,
       "Avatar": "System.Drawing.Bitmap",
       "Id": "17db833c-5008-44f0-a713-a186014c22a5"
   },
]
```

The webservice mthod is

```
<!-- language: lang-c# -->
public IQueryable<User> Get()
{
    // return stuff (no big deal here)
}
```

The code is the same, so why won't JSON return a base64 string like it should?

Comment: It looks like your JSON serializer can't serialize the `Bitmap` type. You probably need to encode it as a plain `byte` array, or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [LukeH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55847/lukeh) said, converting my Bitmap to byte array solved my issues.