# C# - De-serialize class having byte array from string

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class

```
[Serializable]
public class DocumentMetadataBEO
{
    public Guid ItemId { get; private set; }
    public byte[] HashValue { get; set; }
}
```

I am receiving string having both of the above value.

However when i try to deserialize as below -

```
documentMetadata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentMetadataBEO>(responseFromServer);
```

`HashValue` property is getting set null. How can I deserialize it?

Here is the Json format, we get from server

```
"{
    \"ItemId\":\"a1606584-9b9e-4bba-845f-e775eb5ebda5",   
    \"HashValue\":\"UHj5WO00uD5MIeCEr0Bt8i03iMrqUfILky7wSiqIn7g=\
"}"
```

Comment: how does your string look like in `responseFromServer` ?

Comment: Please post an example of the JSON (serialized value) you are attempting to deserialize.

Comment: Here is the Json we get from server "{\"ItemId\":\"a1606584-9b9e-4bba-845f-e775eb5ebda5\",\"HashValue\":\"UHj5WO00uD5MIeCEr0Bt8i03iMrqUfILky7wSiqIn7g=\"}"

Comment: please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44029287/edit) button below your post, to add this information into your question.

Comment: Look up how to decode from Base64 encoded string. You are going to need two steps here. Deserialize the hash to a string, then base64 decode the string to byte[]

Comment: He doesn't need 2 steps.  he can create a custom converter like this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510742/newtonsoft-json-deserializing-base64-image-fails

Comment: @Fran, I try to consider the experience level of the OP. I assume if OP does not recognize base64 encoding that a custom converter might be overwhelming. But, yes, agreed a converter may be in order.

Answer (score 1):

With a newer version of Json.NET, it is working out of the box.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: what is the Json.Net version here?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1 - got it through NuGet package

Comment: This will help if I use latest Json.Net. Thank you