# Deserialization .json to Bitmap image c#

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a bitmap image, which I converted to a JSON file using:

```
string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Bitmap image);
```

Content of .json file:

```
{  
   "Tag":null,
   "PhysicalDimension":{  
      "IsEmpty":false,
      "Width":376,
      "Height":221
   },
   "Size":{  
      "IsEmpty":false,
      "Width":376,
      "Height":221
   },
   "Width":376,
   "Height":221,
   "HorizontalResolution":96,
   "VerticalResolution":96,
   "Flags":2,
   "RawFormat":{  
      "Guid":"b96b3caa-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e"
   },
   "PixelFormat":2498570,
   "Palette":{  
      "Flags":62,
      "Entries":[  

      ]
   },
   "FrameDimensionsList":[  
      "7462dc86-6180-4c7e-8e3f-ee7333a7a483"
   ],
   "PropertyIdList":[  

   ],
   "PropertyItems":[  

   ]
}
```

Now I tried to deserialize the file in this way:

```
Bitmap bm = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Bitmap>(json);
```

But got the error:

> System.MissingMethodException: "For the" System.Bitmap "type, the
>   constructor without parameters is not defined."

Is there another way to deserialize the file or how can I fix this code?

Thanks!

Comment: How's your json look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Newtonsoft.Json deserializing base64 image fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510742/newtonsoft-json-deserializing-base64-image-fails)

Comment: Why would you want to convert a Bitmap (a binary) to json?

Comment: That is my task: convert bitmap to json and vice versa

Comment: To display it? Or what do you do with it?

Comment: @MrsLSD do you realise that your JSON does not contain the actual image, only image properties. And on serialisation you will not be able to display the image again?

Comment: yes, i should to display it on picture box.

Comment: Maybe the question should be "How do I display a Bitmap in a picture box"

Comment: I should convert bitmap to json and load image again from file.json

Comment: @MrsLSD in that case Json serialisation is not suitable here. At least in the form you do it. Why do you need it in JSON anyway?

Comment: you are jsonizing the properties of the Bitmap type not the bitmap itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, I need to do it some way.

I have converted bmp to binary and XML  and vise versa yet

Comment: okey, how to jsoning bitmap itself?^)

Comment: Do you know why you are doing this, or somebody just tasked you to do it?

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? i mean do you need it to save it in a database or... ?

Comment: I want to load this .json file to pictureBox as image

Comment: somebody just talked.

Comment: @MrsLSD Stop. Think about it. You have a binary object that can be saved as a file already. Then you need to show this file in a `pictureBox`. Just read that binary file again and show it. Why involve JSON and serialisation?

Comment: sorry but i don't get it. what is  pictureBox a control ? winform ? wpf? web?

Answer (score 4):

The error of the message is... quite clear on this. If you look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation for `Bitmap`, you'll find that it has no empty constructors defined. The JSON deserializer basically creates an new instance of a specified type (using the empty constructor) then fills out the properties. The `Bitmap` is a bit too complex for that to work. So... you need to work around that.

Bernard Vander Beken already showed you how to read a base64 string containin bitmap data. Here's how you can CREATE it from an existing bitmap:

```
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
var bitmapData = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bitmap, typeof(byte[])));
```

Note that `bitmapData`, in the example above, is a string which can easily be sent, stored, etc. (so no need to serialize this into JSON).

EDIT:

Please note that given the above, you need to update BOTH your serialization and deserialization code. I.e. to use the deserialization samples provided, you need to send / store a completely different JSON from the one you're currently working with... which won't be a JSON any more.

**In fact, your current JSON file doesn't really contain an actual image; it only has some metadata about the image you originally used.** So you definitely need to change the code responsible for serialization.

I would also modify the code for deserializing a bitmap ever so slightly (`MemoryStream` should, in theory, be disposed of properly and setting the position isn't required).

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(bitmapData);
Bitmap bitmap;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
  bitmap = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromStream(ms));
```

Comment: I did it!

Should I add solution ?

Comment: @MrsLSD If what I wrote was the answer you sought, then yes, it would be nice if you marked this as the correct solution. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since Bitmap has no default constructor, it cannot be used out of the box for deserialization.

You can try to deserialize the JSON payload to a byte array, then pass it to Bitmap.FromStream via a MemoryStream.

```
string image = json;

byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer);
memoryStream.Position = 0;

return (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(memoryStream);
```

Credits to http://ingsharksoft.blogspot.be/2013/07/solution-problem-serializedeserialize.html

Comment: I am not sure how an image is serialized.