# Convert picture URL to Bitmap with React & ASP.NET

Tags: c#, reactjs

In my application i need to be able to capture image in browser then send it back to the server where it gets processed. currently i have a widget that captures an image and returns a pictureUrl for png image.

I'm looking for a best possible way to send it back to server.

Ideally i want this image put back inside the class that I originally fetch from server, then serialize it back to JSON and send to server.

Lets say for instance I heve the following C# class:

```
myClassWithImage{
    Bitmap myBitmap = null;
    ///many other properties
}
```

i serialize it to json and send it to the user.

Then i want react to use the instance of this class, update it with the picture, serialize to json & send back updated version.
On server I just want to recreate the class instance using Newtonsoft.JSON like:

```
myClassWithImage imgCl = data.SelectToken("myClassWImage").ToObject<myClassWithImage>();
```

Is this possible at all? Or should i serialize images to base64 string ans send separately?

UPDATE:

I guess what I'm trying to find out if it is possible to serialize/deserialize the object directly into the instance of class without using additional Base64 string properties to it.
If i try to add image Url directly to the myBitmap property I get

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "data:image/png;base64,....

So should i instead introduce another property to this class to hold the value of the image as string during serialization/deserialization?

Comment: Yes it is possible, is it not working? Or what errors are you encountering?  Personally, I'd use a property that's marked as serializable.  Like public bitmap  myBitMap {get;set;} type of thing...

Comment: If i put Base64 value directly into the myBitmap property I get Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting called into a meeting, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510742/newtonsoft-json-deserializing-base64-image-fails