# Removing an element from a JSON response

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON string from which I want to be able to delete some data.

Below is the JSON response:

```
{
  "ResponseType": "VirtualBill",
  "Response": {
    "BillHeader": {
      "BillId": "7134",
      "DocumentId": "MN003_0522060",
      "ConversionValue": "1.0000",
      "BillType": "Vndr-Actual",
      "AccountDescription": "0522060MMMDDYY",
      "AccountLastChangeDate": "06/07/2016"
    }
  },
  "Error": null
}
```

From above JSON response I want to able remove the 
`"ResponseType": "VirtualBill",` part such that it looks like this:

```
{
  "Response": {
    "BillHeader": {
      "BillId": "7134",
      "DocumentId": "MN003_0522060",
      "ConversionValue": "1.0000",
      "BillType": "Vndr-Actual",
      "AccountDescription": "0522060MMMDDYY",
      "AccountLastChangeDate": "06/07/2016"
    }
  },
  "Error": null
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 27):

Using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), you can remove the unwanted property like this:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
jo.Property("ResponseType").Remove();
json = jo.ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BgMQAE

---

If the property you want to remove is nested inside another object, then you just need to navigate to that object using [`SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) and then `Remove` the unwanted property from there.

For example, let's say that you wanted to remove the `ConversionValue` property,  which is nested inside `BillHeader`, which is itself nested inside `Response`.  You can do it like this:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
JObject header = (JObject)jo.SelectToken("Response.BillHeader");
header.Property("ConversionValue").Remove();
json = jo.ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hTlbrt

Comment: this does not work if "ResponseType" is nested element. Can you provide an example for nested elements?

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a `JsonObject`, remove the key, and convert it back to `string`.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you provided details about *how* to do what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sample sample= new Sample();
 var     properties=sample.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x=>x.Name!="ResponseType");
 var response = new Dictionary<string,object>() ;

foreach(var prop in properties)
 {
    var propname = prop.Name;
   response[propname] = prop.GetValue(sample); ;
}

 var response= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
```