# How to validate and remove nested nodes of JSON Object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have below JSON Object

```
{  
   "movieList":[  
      {  
         "movieID":1,
         "title":"TITLE 1",
         "showTimes":[  
            {  
               "date":"xx",
               "time":["11:00" , "15:00" ]
            },
            {  
              "date":"xx",
               "time":["11:00"]
            },
            {  
               "date":"xx",
               "time":["18:00" ]
            },
            {  
              "date":"xx",
               "time":["11:00" , "15:00" , "18:00" ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Wanted to remove the below nodes under "showTimes" array. Here I am trying to remove nodes which doesn't have value "18:00" in "time" property.

```
{  
   "date":"xx",
   "time":["11:00" , "15:00" ]
},
{  
  "date":"xx",
   "time":["11:00"]
}
```

using below code I am able to get time values in foreach loop

```
 StreamReader rs = new StreamReader("xx.json"); 

  string json = rs.ReadToEnd();

  JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);

  JToken jToken = JToken.Parse(json);

 var result = jToken["movieList"].SelectMany(x => x["showTimes"].SelectMany(y => y["time"].Select(z => z)).ToList());

      foreach (var item in result)
        {
          if (item.ToString() != "18:00")
              {
                // item.Parent.Remove();
              }
        }
```

How to remove above nodes from my JSON Object in foreach loop?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with https://app.quicktype.io?share=8CYNaPjpEs2AKwfL0F2x .

Comment: I cannot use model class here , want to return dynamic JSON to UI . time("18:00" )is the input parameter to modify my JSON Object

Comment: Why can't you generate the JSON you need from concrete classes? _I know it feels like I am not helping - but 95% of JSON questions would disappear if people used concrete classes as their starting point._

Comment: Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054986/removing-an-element-from-a-json-response) possible will helpful. However I strogly recommend for you @mjwills comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing an element from a JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054986/removing-an-element-from-a-json-response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will also suggest using model class, but for your case this should work

```
 JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
 JToken jToken = JToken.Parse(json);

 var result = jToken["movieList"].SelectMany(x => x["showTimes"]).ToList();

 foreach (var item in result)
 {
   var times = item.SelectTokens("time").Values().ToList();    
   if (!times.Where(x => x.ToString().Trim() == "18:00").Any())
   {
       item.Remove();
   }
 }

 var output = jToken.ToString(Formatting.Indented);   
 Console.WriteLine(output);
```

output

```
{
  "movieList": [
    {
      "movieID": 1,
      "title": "TITLE 1",
      "showTimes": [
        {
          "date": "xx",
          "time": [
            "18:00"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "xx",
          "time": [
            "11:00",
            "15:00",
            "18:00"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Linq to query for nodes that doesn't contain "18:00" in time and remove them. For example,

```
var jToken = JToken.Parse(json);
var result = jToken["movieList"].SelectMany(x=>x["showTimes"])
                            .Select(x=>x["time"])
                            .Where(x=>!x.Any(c=>c.Value<string>()=="18:00"))
                            .ToList();
foreach(var item in result)
     item.Parent.Parent.Remove();
var output = jToken.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Sample Output

```
{
  "movieList": [
    {
      "movieID": 1,
      "title": "TITLE 1",
      "showTimes": [
        {
          "date": "xx",
          "time": [
            "18:00"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "xx",
          "time": [
            "11:00",
            "15:00",
            "18:00"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `item.Parent.Remove()`, try just `item.Remove()`:

```
var json = "{  \r\n   \"movieList\":[  \r\n      {  \r\n         \"movieID\":1,\r\n         \"title\":\"TITLE 1\",\r\n         \"showTimes\":[  \r\n            {  \r\n               \"date\":\"xx\",\r\n               \"time\":[\"11:00\" , \"15:00\" ]\r\n            },\r\n            {  \r\n              \"date\":\"xx\",\r\n               \"time\":[\"11:00\"]\r\n            },\r\n            {  \r\n               \"date\":\"xx\",\r\n               \"time\":[\"18:00\" ]\r\n            },\r\n            {  \r\n              \"date\":\"xx\",\r\n               \"time\":[\"11:00\" , \"15:00\" , \"18:00\" ]\r\n            }\r\n         ]\r\n      }\r\n   ]\r\n}";

var jToken = JToken.Parse(json);

var result = jToken["movieList"].SelectMany(x => x["showTimes"].SelectMany(y => y["time"].Select(z => z)).ToList());

foreach (var item in result)
{
    if (item.ToString() != "18:00")
    {
        item.Remove();
    }
}

var output = jToken.ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```

Output:

```
{
  "movieList": [
    {
      "movieID": 1,
      "title": "TITLE 1",
      "showTimes": [
        {
          "date": "xx",
          "time": []
        },
        {
          "date": "xx",
          "time": []
        },
        {
          "date": "xx",
          "time": [
            "18:00"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": "xx",
          "time": [
            "18:00"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you test this? This doesn't look like OP's requirement

Comment: @ssilas777 yes I did test it. What about it doesn't look like the OP's requirement?

Comment: Check the out put he wanted and the output you getting

Comment: {  
               "date":"xx",
               "time":["18:00" ]
            },
            {  
              "date":"xx",
               "time":["11:00" , "15:00" , "18:00" ]
            }.. This should be his output

Comment: @ssilas777 I read it as OP wanting to remove the nodes which aren't equal to "18:00" which is what his code sample is trying to do

Comment: @ssilas777 fair enough. Maybe in the question the OP should have put the expected output JSON to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ssilas777 wanted to remove entire node instead of making array empty. so trying as Parent.remove()                                                                                      {  
   "date":"xx",
   "time":["11:00" , "15:00" ]
},
{  
  "date":"xx",
   "time":["11:00"]
}

Comment: @user2038538 check my answer