# remove from a json object

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON object. I need to remove dynamicObject from the JSON, but not the fields under it.
example  this is how I am passing it

var item = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someRequest);
Below is the result.

```
{
  "email_address": "test@yah.com",
  "status": "subscribed",
  "merge_fields": {
    "dynamicObject": {
      "FirstName": "Jack",
      "LastName": "Sparrow"
    }
  }
}
```

it should look like

```
{
  "email_address": "test@yah.com",
  "status": "subscribed",
  "merge_fields": {
    "FirstName": "Jack",
    "LastName": "Sparrow"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054986/removing-an-element-from-a-json-response) help?

Comment: @AliK it doesn't seem like the OP wants to actually remove the object. They just want to write at a different level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to create a temporary [anonymous object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types) that has the structure that you need, and then `Serialize` that:

```
var obj = new
{
    email_address = someRequest.email_address,
    status = someRequest.status, 
    merge_fields = someRequest.merge_fields.dynamicObject
};
var item = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var jsonParsed=JObject.Parse(item);

jsonParsed["merge_fields"]=jsonParsed["merge_fields"]["dynamicObject"];

item=jsonParsed.ToString();
```