# Json.NET prevent specific type(s) from serializing without attributes

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I tried searching google and stackoverflow for this simple question but had no luck.

When using Json.NET I want to serialize an object with all of the fields except a specific type.

I don't want to mark every field/property with JsonIgnore to prevent serialization instead what I want to do is just mark the specific type as "NonSerialized". This of course won't work. Is there anyway to achieve it without marking properties and fields with attributes?

I tried resolving this using DefaultContractResolver but didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: Explained in the first web search hit on "json.net exclude type": [Exclude property from serialization via custom attribute (json.net)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588022/exclude-property-from-serialization-via-custom-attribute-json-net). Don't get confused by the title, the answers work without attributes.

Comment: Thanks, I did find the linked question on google but for some reason couldn't apply it to my code, after looking at it again and refactoring my code I noticed I made a mistake. The ShouldSerialize method always returned true. Changed some code and it works perfect.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use the [JavaScriptSerializer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and implement a [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which excludes the properties you don't need. You can then register that converter on the `JavaScriptSerializer` using its `RegisterConverters` method.

Comment: I'm restricted to the Newtonsoft's Json.NET serializer