# Newtonsoft Json.NET ignore default datetime values when serializing

Tags: json, json.net

How to setup `JsonSerializer` to ignore DateTime properties with default value `0001-01-01T00:00:00`, but to serialize enums and numbers with default values at the same time?

this ignores also enums:

```
_jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
_jsonSerializer.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
```

and this includes also default datetimes:

```
_jsonSerializer.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is similar question and is answered: [Exclude property from serialization via custom attribute (json.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588022/exclude-property-from-serialization-via-custom-attribute-json-net)

It refers to [Conditional Property Serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm) article in json.net docs

```
_jsonSerializer.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include;
_jsonSerializer.ContractResolver = new MyShouldSerializeContractResolver();
```