# Mixing Bind And FromBody Attributes MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following controller action

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public void Put(int id, [Bind("BirthDate")][FromBody]ExpandoObject value)
{
   _dataContext.Update(value);
}
```

I am trying to limit the allowed properties, and I assumed this would work, however, it doesn't and value receives all the values sent and not just BirthDate - I don't want to use a view model because I want a dynamic object to be sent. FYI, this doesn't work with a normal model object either.

this is the json I am sending in request the body

```
{
      "FirstName": "Lionell",
      "LastName": "Messi",
      "BirthDate": "2009-04-06T11:54:29.047",
      "PhoneNumber": "1234567890",
      "EmailAddress": "blabla@gmail.com",
      "SchoolId": 1,
      "IsIndependent": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the source code, when posting a json in the request body, the [`BodyModelBinder`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/BodyModelBinder.cs) is used. Unfortunately this model binder doesn't seem to apply the PropertyFilters provided by instances of the `IPropertyBindingPredicateProvider` like the `[Bind]` attribute.

It just uses the [`JsonInputFormatter`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/028c0fb13164bcdda2e22e01e9093ac8a5853b06/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonInputFormatter.cs) to deserialize the json into the model type:

```
var formatters = bindingContext.OperationBindingContext.InputFormatters;
var formatter = formatters.FirstOrDefault(f => f.CanRead(formatterContext));

...

try
{
    var previousCount = bindingContext.ModelState.ErrorCount;
    var result = await formatter.ReadAsync(formatterContext);
    var model = result.Model;
```

This seems like a bug to me...

In the meantime, you could try to evaluate some options you have available. As stated in [the docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/model-binding.html?highlight=frombody#binding-formatted-data-from-the-request-body) we know the formatter uses Json.Net:

> The `JsonInputFormatter` is the default formatter and it is based off of
>   Json.NET.

So essentially you would need to follow an approach to exclude the properties that works with Json.Net, like using the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute. (Or just use some DTO object that doesn't contains those properties :))

Of course in your case is harder because you have a dynamic object and not a strongly typed object, which means:

1. There is no type for you to apply the attributes
2. Json.net will be unaware of any attributes you set in the controller action.

You could explore updating the `JsonSerializerSettings`, for example trying to use a [contract resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588022/exclude-property-from-serialization-via-custom-attribute-json-net) to dynamically exclude properties. You might possible need some global configuration that links routes and parameters to be ignored, so you can decide when to ignore a property or not based on the current request.

All of this would be much easier if it was fixed by Microsoft so it works out of the box!