# Json.NET - How to exclude properties from Serialization without access to class

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am trying to serialize a class using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Here's what I do for the moment.

```
public class AClass
{
    // I don't have access to BClass
    public BClass b;
}

AClass a = new AClass();
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
```

I don't have access to `BClass`. I want to serialize my `AClass` but I don't want to serialize all properties of `BClass`, only some of them.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588022/exclude-property-from-serialization-via-custom-attribute-json-net

Answer (score 9):

You can use a custom `ContractResolver`, [this library](https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/JsonDotNetCustomContractResolvers) will make it easier to build.

```
var propertiesContractResolver = new PropertiesContractResolver();
propertiesContractResolver.ExcludeProperties.Add("BClass.Id");
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.ContractResolver = propertiesContractResolver;
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a, serializerSettings);
```

Comment: You have to add a dependency on a nuget package just to not serialize a field ?

Comment: I don't see a problem with this. You can always copy the source or write your own if you do not like nuget.

Comment: This nuget package very helpful as I had two different serialization needs for the same object.  Unusual, yes.  This was perfect.  Works great, too.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ideas come to mind, which you can choose from depending on how many distinct classes you need to do this for and how performant you need the algorithm to be:

Probably the fastest would be to use Json.net's **[custom converters](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)** or **[Contract Resolvers](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm)** and build one that suits your needs, i.e. ignores properties you don't want included.

Another approach would be to map this class to another similarly-defined class that simply doesn't contain the properties you don't want included, and then serialize that class. You can use **[AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/)** for quick mapping between similarly-defined classes.

Finally, you can create an `ExpandoObject` (or even a `Dictionary<string, object>`) and add the properties that you want included into the Expando or the Dictionary (and you can copy those properties/key-value pairs either manually or by reflection, etc.) and then serialize that object/dictionary.