# Omit certain fields for specific Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have the following line in my .NET Core code :

```
var serializedstuff = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myuserclass);
```

What I want to do is to omit almost all fields with the exception of two in that *specific* serialization. I know I can annotate the class to make this happen, but I want to have a full serialization in all other cases except for this one.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: I'm guessing it's something like this you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59227350/94940 
Perhaps you want to rewrite it to only take as parameter what properties to include?

Comment: Exactly, thanks so much.

Comment: What is `JSON.SerializeObject`?  Is it `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject` from [tag:json.net]?

Comment: For Json.NET see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14510134/3744182) to [Exclude property from serialization via custom attribute (json.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13588022/3744182).

Comment: @dbc Yes it is.

Comment: In that case I think this should be a duplicate of the two linked answers.  Agree?

Comment: yes of course. You can close this as a duplicate.