# Conditionally ignore a property field from object JavascriptSerializer

Tags: c#, serialization

I use the `JavascriptSerializer` to serialize an object like this:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class Group
{
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public string Comment;

    public string GroupName;
}
```

Now I would like to reuse the same object with the same `Comment` property for a different serialization problem.

- In the **first** case I would like to `ScriptIgnore` the `Comment` field
- In the **second** case I would like to not ignore that field.

Is there a programmatic way to choose whether to ignore or not the `Comment` field just before serializing the object using an external condition, or I'm forced to create a second object with only one field of difference ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make JavaScriptSerializer ignore properties of a certain generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851899/is-there-a-way-to-make-javascriptserializer-ignore-properties-of-a-certain-gener)